# Does Go support Indexer Methods?

Tags: go

Many programming languages have Indexers that allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Is this possible in Go? what it's called and how it's implemented?

Indexer Methods in C#:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/

```
SomeReturnType this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        return SomeField[i];
    }
    set
    {
        SomeField[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No it does not. The best thing you can have is a slice and work with this.

I answered the question since a lot of people coming from other languages learn that way trying to implement something. And the docs don't offer a comparison of the limitations that go has compared to other languages

Comment: can it be used in classes?

Comment: @DreamsMaker there are only structs in Go. But it cannot be used in structs the same way. You can thing of a slice like a more robust and powerful array the Go offers

Comment: @DreamsMaker: Go doesn't have any classes, so no.